# exit for-loop with if-statement

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, exit

I have an iterative problem that I want to solve with a `for`-loop. However, once my conditions are met, I want to break from the `for`-loop. I have an `if`-statement to check for my condition to be satisfied.
But the `if`-statement never catches the condition it is supposed to.
Here is a reduced example of my code. The `if`-statement is exactly how it is in my code, but the `for`-loop and `delta_Q` are simplified.

```
for ii=1:1000
    delta_Q = rand(1)*10-5
    if 0.01 < delta_Q < -0,01
        disp(['delta_Q too small, last index:', num2str(ii)])
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: @Ander Biguri here is the code

Comment: `if 0.01 < delta_Q <-0,01` is invalid MATLAB syntax.  You can't chain Boolean conditions that way like you would in Python.  You must specifically do: `if delta_Q < -0.01 && delta_Q > 0.01`

Comment: @rayryeng I tried but still :(

Comment: Print out `delta_Q` each time it's calculated and see if its absolute value ever gets below `0.01`. You should also check your `if` condition by itself to make sure it's returning the values you expect.

Answer (score 0):

As [rayryeng pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33244751/matlab-exit-for-loop#comment54291990_33244751), this line in your code does not do what you think it does:

```
0.01 < delta_Q < -0,01
```

1. The Boolean conditions need to be separated
2. `-0,01` is not the same as `-0.01`, rather it is `0` and `1`
3. However:

   ```
   0.01 < delta_Q && delta_Q < -0.01
   ```

   does not make sense, because you cannot at the same time be both greater than `0.01` and smaller than `-0.01`

Therefore, if you change your conditions to:

```
-0.01 < delta_Q && delta_Q < 0.01
```

You get the desired behavior.

---

All this can be found out with [simple debugging steps](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html).